# Fallout 4 will not get past the initial loading screen

Tags: technical-issues, pc, fallout-4

I am attempting to launch either vanilla or modded Fallout 4, but either way, I cannot get past the initial loading screen. It freezes the second the circle in the bottom right corner comes up.

Since I am using Nexus Mod Manager, I thought that was the problem and uninstalled all mods I had loaded and disabled all mods checked. Still, that did not fix the problem. I have since wiped everything from the Fallout 4 folder and reinstalled the game completely - but it still won't launch.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever play the game? (ala: Did it stop working, or did it never work on your system?)

Comment: @Sumurai8 I have completed the main story and also have passed the recommended system requirements.

Comment: Was there anything significant you did before it stopped launching? Update drivers, download DLC, etc.?

Comment: If using Steam, have you tried validating install? 

Right click the game in your library, and select Properties. Go to the local files tab, and select "Verify Integrity of Game Cache".

Comment: @pushasha Adding mods via Nexus Mod Manager and changing some .ini files because it said something about "The old Fallout4.asi (or some file name like that) has slow loading times."

Comment: @Kaizerwolf All of my files were validated but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Actually, looking at the answer below, check your Fallout 4 launcher. Under options, check to make sure that the Resolution is set properly. I've noticed with previous Bethesda games, it will randomly reset that Resolution to something lower than my current, and the game refuses to launch. Could be a possibility.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I did modify my resolutions to downscale Half-Life 2 from 4k to 1080p (my monitor's standard resolution), but since DSR was enabled, that would put the other resolutions question as not the problem and I still crash when Fallout 4 is at 1080p.

Answer (score 1):

You must also delete `C:\Users\*your name*\AppData\Local\Fallout4` –*Fallout 4 crashes on startup*, [community.bethesda.net](https://community.bethesda.net/thread/23424?start=0&tstart=0)

This directory contains your mod and .esp load order (save it somewhere else!), which the program is calling for and cannot access because they don't exist anymore. (= crash)

Answer (score 0):

The last time that I had that issue was when I tried to run Fallout 4 on a computer that couldn't handle the graphics, check your graphics card and make sure it can handle Fallout 4 even on minimal graphic settings.

Comment: GeForce GTX 970, Intel i7-3820 @ 3.60 GHz Overclocked 4 Core, 16 GB of RAM, and Windows 10 64-bit. I think I'm good.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow did you try it? "I think i'm good", well that is just obviously false, you are here asking a question because it doesn't work :).

Comment: @Mixxiphoid The "think I'm good" was for the specs.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow I understand that, but did you try it?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I opened Fallout 4 on that PC, and the issue still persists.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered to look into the papyrus logs?
If i remember correctly you can activate logging in the Fallout4.ini. The logs will be generated in the user folder in Documents/Fallout4/logs. This maybe give you a hint what goes wrong.