# Why is Fallout 4 delivering infinite loading upon new game?

Tags: steam, fallout-4, windows-10

I recently bought a copy of Fallout 4 via Steam.
The game launches successfully, but when I select new game the loading gets stuck there. The screen doesn't freeze, it just doesn't load. Obviously there's no load existing game option because I've never played it before. I've waited for 20+ minutes for the new game to load but it hasn't. My specs are OK.
I searched the internet for similar problems, I tried all advices, such as running steam and fallout as administrator, verifying data files, running in windowed mode, not using mods, deleting ini files in my documents folder, running in borderless windowed mode, updating nvidia drivers, disabling nvidia streaming service, etc etc.
It seems a lot of people are having trouble with this game on Windows PC.
I checked dxdiag and it shows some strange WER error about Fallout 4 (the language of my windows 10 is pt-br, dx v12):

```
---------------
Diagnostics
---------------

Windows Error Reporting:
+++ WER0 +++:
Falha no bucket 129232755241, tipo 5
Nome do Evento: RADAR_PRE_LEAK_64
Resposta: Não disponível
ID do CAB: 0

Assinatura do problema:
P1: Fallout4.exe
P2: 1.7.22.0
P3: 10.0.14393.2.0.0
P4: 
P5: 
P6: 
P7: 
P8: 
P9: 
P10: 

Arquivos anexados:
\\?\C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Temp\RDR8C7.tmp\empty.txt
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER8D8.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

Esses arquivos podem estar disponíveis em:

Símbolo da análise: 
Verificando novamente solução: 0
ID do Relatório: 8da33b82-97f9-11e6-a8d1-d8cb8acc037c
Status do Relatório: 0
Bucket com hash: 1c20cd6b5b9741553678acad0e2b5062
```

I suppose this might be a compatibility issue related to motherboard or RAM memory, but I'm just an intermediate Windows user and I'd never seen those WER messages before.
Any deeper suggestions?

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269877/my-fallout-4-will-not-get-past-the-initial-loading-screen/287499#287499); the one pertinent file location you don't seem to mention: `C:\Users\*your name*\AppData\Local\Fallout4`, although I don't see why a first time install would have a problem via the files in it.

Comment: Have you ever before installed F4 on this computer or run any mods?

Comment: Well, the mentioned post is related but not the same issue; my loading screen doesn't freeze. I'd never run F4 or any mods before on this machine, this is a brand new install. I will delete the mentioned file and try it again.

Comment: Use a page file set at like 12gigs. Disable any video card overclocking. Do not "upgrade" to Windows 10, either downgrade back or do a fresh install of real W10. That's what I came up with when I googled "RADAR_PRE_LEAK_64" + Fallout 4. You might also try re-running the redistributables. Indeed it seems a lot of people are having problems on Windows *10*, and the suggestions are all over the place, with few people reporting success when they try them. Please do get back to us if you figure it out.

Comment: ""Disabling a feature called "AMD Turbo Core Tech" sounds like the first thing you should try. [This thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/494631967652714050/?ctp=2) is where I found most of the above info; almost every part of it is echoed in other threads elsewhere.

Comment: Try to add the parameter -32 in game (Fallout 4) properties in steam. It'll initialize in 32bits mod.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann, your answer solved the problem! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Lucas glad it helped you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the parameter -32 in game (Fallout 4) properties in steam. It'll initialize in 32bits mod.