# Fallout 3 Crashes when trying to exit Vault 101?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, fallout-3

So I decided to start playing Fallout 3, in the build up to Fallout 76 releasing sometime later this year(hopefully). along with the other Fallout Games. I loaded Fallout 3 and played through the first quest, Escape!, and as I open the Vault door towards the end of the quest, the game becomes unresponsive, and I cannot move my character. Interestingly enough, the sound files continue to play as if the game is still running.

I have all the DLC Packs for Fallout 3, and have them enabled from the get go in the main launcher, so I tried disabling them and tried launching the game from it's core .esm file, no dice. I have NO mods in this game whatsoever, so mods cannot be the issue.

I am out of ideas to try and get the game to start working again, any ideas? Maybe something to do with the game's console?

Thanks for viewing!

Comment: Are you using steam? Could you link the version of your fallout-3? Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Do the console commands work while you are unresponsive? You could use the coc (Center Of Cell) command to force your way out of the vault.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 I was thinking of using the console, but I was afraid that the quest would be incomplete if I left the Vault Door closed at the end of the Quest. I did try and use the console in game, but now the game is completely unresponsive, with the console now not operating at all.

Comment: @creulcat No I am not using Steam here, I got the game as a gift on Disc sometime back with all the DLCs on it. How do you check the version of the game? I'm not sure on how to do that (is there a setting in game or something?), and regarding the operating system, I'm using Windows 10 Pro on a laptop with a i7-7820HK and a GTX 1080 8GB.

Comment: @GipsyD the console can also be used to progress any quest along too. Just start a new game, set up your stats and whenever you gain complete control over your character, use coc to get out and quest progress commands (not sure of it's name) to bring the quest up to where you need to be.

Comment: As I told @creulcat, I am using Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Has F3 [ever been installed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269877/fallout-4-will-not-get-past-the-initial-loading-screen?rq=1) on this computer? Before it hangs, coc to an interior cell somewhere far away, then go outside. If it still crashes I dunno, but if it only crashes when you go by 101 (happened to me) then don't go by 101 anymore. I use NV to play F3 so whatever was causing that isn't really a problem anymore. Just head to the bar in Mega to pick up the *find daddy* quest.

Comment: Ensure every esp and esm is where it should be (the dlc might not be - and exiting the vault is when those get loaded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be to try and alter some settings in the game.
Go to the installationfolder of your game and locate the file `FalloutPrefs.ini` this file might be located in the submap Fallout3.
Open this file with a texteditor such as notepad and find the following line and change its value `bDoHighDynamicRange=0` to `bDoHighDynamicRange=1`

Try to start the game and exit the vault. If this doesn't work, you could try some other settings.
For this you'll need to find the file Fallout_default.ini also located in the gamefolder.
Find the following values and change them:
Change `bUseThreadedAI=0` to `bUseThreadedAI=1`
Change `iNumHWThreads=2` to `iNumHWThreads=1`

If either of these options don't exist, you should add them in the `[General]` block of settings.

What this will do:
**bDoHighDynamicRange** turns on [HDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-dynamic-range_rendering).
**bUseThreadedAI** determines if actors' behavior scripts can be split into multiple threads. This might improve performance*
**iNumHWThreads** controls the number of threads the game uses in general. *

*[Link for more information > Fallout.ini (Gamebryo)](https://fallout.gamepedia.com/Fallout.ini_(Gamebryo))

Comment: This answer is gold! Should have accepted it earlier. For some bizzare reason, my game was only using 2 threads on a 8 thread CPU :p. Fixed it now and the game works just fine. Thanks again!